# Understanding HTML 5 event drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I do not understand why the returning value for mouse coordinate clientX in event drag is always 0 or a negative value just before releasing the mouse.

I have prepare an example, when user `dragstart`, mouse position is correct, same for end `dragend`... but if you look at the console for `drag` you will see before `dragend` a negative value.

Is a normal behavior? Why? I need to avoid this 0 value. any solutions?

http://jsfiddle.net/gg8gLpg0/

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
    #test {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;    
        background-color:red;
    }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" draggable="true">test</div>
        <script>
        var elm = document.getElementById('test');

        elm.addEventListener('drag', function (event) {
            //console.log(event.clientX);
            //console.log(event.clientY);
        }.bind(this));

        elm.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
            console.log('start');
            console.log(event.clientX);
            console.log(event.clientY);
        }.bind(this));

        elm.addEventListener('drag', function (event) {
            console.log('during drag');// PROBLEM HERE
            console.log(event.clientX);
            console.log(event.clientY);
        }.bind(this));

        elm.addEventListener('dragend', function (event) {
            console.log('end');
            console.log(event.clientX);
            console.log(event.clientY);
        }.bind(this));


        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Something tells me you can't, but why not just check `if ( event.clientX < 0 )` to see if it's negative, and if so just return.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gg8gLpg0/1/

Comment: @adeneo thanks for your work around, but why is that? A bug?

Comment: @adeneo what could be an alternative to event drag?

Comment: I have no idea why it's like that, and I don't think there is an alternative event, you probably just have to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests on Firefox the drag element ONLY fires a 0. 
AND, the drag event stopped the "mousemove" event from reaching the document level to capture it that way.

jsfiddle.net/qgedt70a/

Mozilla's official docs say the clientX is local for dragged objects and screenX is global coordinates, however both return 0 from the drag event in variations of my tests at the above jsfiddle.

Could be a bug. OR, I'm curious if they have disabled it for some strange security scenario?